# C# - Having issues getting the Main Window Handle for Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: c#

I am working on a project where one of the objectives is to hide the Adobe Creative Cloud desktop interface from the desktop/ taskbar. I am familiar with how you normally would go about hiding a window for example:

```
    public void Hide()
    {
        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
        {

            if (pr.ProcessName.Contains("foo"))
            {

                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);

            }
        }
    }
```

Now I understand that applications sometimes return a hWnd id of 0. Which is what I am getting so to get around this issue you would usually use Refresh() against the process. Again this is working fine for every other application but for some reason it doesn't work for Adobe Creative Cloud.

Am I missing something here, is there any other solution such as hiding a window/ process based solely off the window title (I have been searching for two days for something like this but everyone seems to suggest using Main Window Handle)? If you guys have Adobe CC installed could you try returning the Main Window Handle on your systems and let me know if you are getting something other than 0. (OS Win10- Not sure how this helps but I thought I'd mention it)

Thanks, 
Umais

Comment: do you know the process name?

Comment: I have Adobe CC on another machine so I can offer some assistance later, but if you know the process name there is more I can help you with

Comment: Cheers Simon. Yeah sure the process name is simply Creative Cloud.

Comment: Hey Simon, any updates on this?

Comment: my apologies, I had a few things come up and I forgot. I will set a reminder for myself later today and get a response for you later

Answer (score 0):

The process name that youre looking for is Adobe Desktop Service so your code needs to be

```
Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
{

    if (pr.ProcessName == "Adobe Desktop Service")
    {
        var hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
        // hWnd.Dump(); // xxx.Dump() is for linqpad output
    }
}
```

try that and let me konw

[image]

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for that but again even after updating the string to Adobe Desktop Services for some reason I still get a hWnd return of 0. It's fine though I'll keep experimenting and try I'll try it on another machine later to see if I can resolve this issue. Thanks again for taking your time to help me!

Comment: some steps that you could follow is have a look in your processes, find the process ID, find that and then find the name of the service thats running from the pr value and then try from there

Comment: @UmaisKhan have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry my bad Simon I completely forgot to reply. Yes your method did work Adobe was just acting funny for me for some reason at first after a re-install it worked fine. Even though I don't see how a re-install could fix the issue it has done lol. Anyways thanks again and sorry for the megga late response!

Comment: @UmaisKhan thats great, if you can make this as the correct answer and up vote it that would be great thanks